# Failed binding port to Ruby application on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, heroku

I want to host a Ruby on Rails app as a Docker container on Heroku. But it seems to have an issue with port binding when deployed.

I successfully hosted a simple Ruby app via Docker locally and on Heroku then I moved to the actual app. The app works fine on localhost but it gets the  port binding issue:

> Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

```
2019-05-06T18:23:13.608790+00:00 app[web.1]: Digest::Digest is deprecated; use Digest
2019-05-06T18:23:15.826137+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma 2.7.1 starting...
2019-05-06T18:23:15.826185+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
2019-05-06T18:23:15.826188+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2019-05-06T18:23:15.826189+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
2019-05-06T18:24:03.338792+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2019-05-06T18:24:03.338920+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2019-05-06T18:24:03.468261+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-05-06T18:24:03.451392+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2019-05-06T18:24:05.407120+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=floating-spire-20546.herokuapp.com request_id=9362ea3c-bcb6-476a-a5d4-76c82cd443a3 fwd="5.151.93.202" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I tried configuring `$PORT` variable on Heroku to 3000. I also tried running the app with `rails server -b 0.0.0.0`. I tried without any port too.

I am thinking it may be due to the size of the app and multiple gems to be loaded which may exceed 60 seconds.

I expect the app to bind to the port to be accessed. However, it crashed.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#r10-boot-timeout

Comment: It makes sense. I think this must be the issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I tried configuring `$PORT` variable on Heroku to 3000

That's not how the `PORT` environment variable works. You don't get to set it to the value you want to use; *Heroku* sets it and *you* must bind to the port it gives you.

For example, if you're using Puma you might [include the `-p` option in your `Procfile`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5#create-a-procfile):

```
web: bundle exec puma -p ${PORT:-3000}
```

Here we use the value given by `$PORT`, falling back to `3000` in case it isn't set (e.g. on your development machine).

Comment: Thank you, that's a good point. However, my issue is because of the time the app takes to build dependencies and boot. It exceeds the time Heroku allows for port binding (60 seconds) so I had to contact the team to request more boot time for the app - devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#r10-boot-timeout

Comment: Why is your application building dependencies during boot? Normally that would be done at build time. Anyway, glad you found a solution. And I'm glad my answer helped.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to use a different startup script.
I used `CMD ["bundle", "exec", "puma" ,"-C" ,"config/puma.rb"]`
 instead of `rails server -b 0.0.0.0`